# In ASP.NET MVC application : how to save the file in another server folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, in which we have implemented to upload file and place it in project folder, but client needs to upload all files to another server - not to the project folder.

I have implemented different approaches, but I'm not able to find the right approach. Please help me.